# how to plot log-log histogram in Mathematica 7

Tags: plotting

I have a large array of real (positive and negative) numbers and I want to plot the histogram of it. I can use

```
Histogram[data, "Log", PlotRange->All]
```

but this gives me log scale only in X-axis. How would you get log scale on both axis for a histogram? I have heard that Mathematica 8 has added this feature, but I am using Mathematica 7 right now.

Moreover, say I just want Log scale on Y-axis. Is it possible too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure if this also works in *Mathematica* 7 since I use version 8/9 but try the following:

```
Histogram[Range@100, {"Log", 10}, "LogCount"]
```

This results in

[image: result]

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488052/plot-a-histogram-with-log-scale-in-mathematica-8) to this.

Comment: With this code it gives me an error message: "Expected a list of tick specifications". Though I don't get this error message for smaller data sets!